# IIS 8.5: A process serving application pool 'AppPool name' failed to respond to a ping

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, application-pool, was, web-garden

I am running an ASP.NET MVC application on IIS 8.5.9600.16384 under Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard. Sometimes I get below error in the event log that makes my application not responding for a while.

Event ID 5010 - Source: WAS

> A process serving application pool 'AppPool name' failed to respond to
> a ping. The process id was '.

My website uses Web Garden and its application pool is set to 4 worker processes and using mode StateServer. Also application pool identity is set to a domain account.

ASP.NET State service runs in the same machine where my site is published.

Any ideas about what could be the problem?

Comment: This error indicates that the Windows Process Activation Service is not running or occurs during the startup or shutdown of the application pool. To solve this problem you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc734991(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN